# GN: overlapping curve points with float attribute - select points with min / max values at the same coordinate

Tags: geometry-nodes

- I have complex curve object (mesh converted to curve) with overlapping curve points (every former edge becomes curve line - mesh with quad polygons will have 4 points at each former vertex)
- This curve object has float field, each curve point has different float attribute.
- I need to select 1 point of those sharing same coordinate with min / max float attribute. How would one do that?
- bonus question: at the end I need to transfer these selected points attributes to original mesh vertices, it appears tricky to do that from curve to mesh, how to do that?

Here is example blend file, float attributes are visualized as line instances, they are also overlapping (4 at each original point coordinate)

- [image]

**Bigger picture:**
Im trying to create GN setup to calculate min. radius, max. radius, mean curvature and so on.
I have working solution for curvature of lines / edge loops (curvature graph), Im trying to modify this setup to create attribute to use for analytic shaders.
Im converting mesh to curve and perform operations on that, because its easy to offset points on curve and get neighbour values.
For more context see here.
https://blenderartists.org/t/surface-diagnostics-addon-for-evaluating-surface-quality/1466262